# Why not a Next page link in StackExchange search results page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I often use [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) to search all other sites. To navigate across the search results pages, at the bottom, I really find it hard to move my cursor over the **tiny** page links and click on the numbers each time for each page.

While all the sites in the StackExchange network have **legible Next Page links**, why cannot the parent StackExchange site(as depicted below, but not that ugly)? Only because of the search being powered by google? (Just a guess)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Google's custom search. But there is a [solution](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/TIYSQORsZ-I) that could be implemented either by SE or as an user script.

Comment: The link requires one to log in to Google.